# Compute: $\int_{\partial B(0,r)} \frac{(z-a)dz}{(z+a)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to calculate the complex integral:

$$\int_{\partial B(0,1)} \frac{(z-a)dz}{(z+a)}$$

When $|a|<1$ and $|a|>1$.

In the first case I believe the Cauchy integral formula can be applied with $f(z)=z-a$. I get $-4\pi  ia$ as an answer then. Is there any way of easily computing the second case, other than going through the long process of computing the integral?

Comment: Well for $|a|>1$ you can expand the denominator in terms of powers $z/a$ and use the general formula for powers of $z$ whereat no negative power appears, so it must be zero. Doesn't seem like a long process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $|a|>1$, the integrand $\frac{z-a}{z+a}$ is holomorphic on $B(0,1)$, therefore by Cauchy’s integral theorem the integral equals zero.